# Frequent dropouts when playing music

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, music

After updating my MacOS to 12.7.3, I found that playing music (mostly MP3 files) is strongly impaired: I get frequent "dropout", i.e. a short pause of maybe half a second.

After some experimenting, I collected the following observations:

- The occurances sometimes, BUT NOT ALWAYS, seem to occur at exactly the time I do something which updates a large part of the screen: For instance switching in the web browser to a different browser text editor tab, or switching to a different MacOS Space. However, this does not happen all the time, and the dropouts occasionally also occur when I'm not even touching my MacBook.
- Thinking that this could be related due to the need of swapping, I checked the ActivityMonotor and found for the CPU, that I am typically using 12GB out of 20. The data for "Cached Files" shows around 4GB, "SwapUsed" shows 20MB.
- I found that the frequency of the dropouts also depend on what tool I use to play music:

  Foobar 2000 : Perhaps 15-20 occurances per hour
  IINA : Perhaps 10-15 occurances
  VLC : Perhaps 5-10 occurances

Interestingly, I did not get so far any dropouts at all when using Apple's builtin Quicktime Player, or when I am playing music from YouTube, using Google Chrome.

Of course I could stick with Quicktime and just don't research the issue further, but for various reasons, I like and want to use the features present in i.e. Foobar 2000. Also I didn't have any playback problems before the version update.

**UPDATE** : While I didn't find the reason for the problems, it seems that a simple reboot did the job. I don't reboot every day, and the problem persisted for two full days. Then I shut down the Mac and when I booted up again, everything went smoothly.

Comment: It's amazing sometimes what a simple reboot can solve. Can you please post it as an answer instead of a question update?

Comment: @nohillside : Not sure that this is appropriate as answer. It incidentally seemed to help to resolve the issue, but doesn't explain what happens. A more careful test would have been to, i.e., first logout and log in again, or to close all applications except the player. After all it could just be that one of the many small applications I sometimes run, steal from time to the the CPU so much, that audio playback is impaired. If I have this problem again, AND reboot helps again, perhaps it would be worth as an answer....